# How do I fix my code for me to be able to use my multi-user login with database?

Tags: c#, database, authentication

I need to log-in with two different users called "Admin" and "Frontdesk" in my login form that's connected to localhost myphp database. I tried looking for ways in the internet but none of them worked for me. Whenever I click the login button, nothing happens. Can anyone please tell me why? Thank you in advance!

```
    private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=root;database=csharp_hotel_db");


        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '"+tbuser.Text+ "'AND `password` = '" + tbpass.Text + "'", connection);
        MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);

        String cmb = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();

        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i>dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                if (dt.Rows[i][3].ToString()== cmb)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("You are logged in as " + dt.Rows[i][3]);
                    if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)
                    {
                        admin ad = new admin();
                        ad.Show();
                        this.Hide();

                    }                    

                    else
                    {
                        frontdesk frontdesk = new frontdesk();
                        frontdesk.Show();
                        this.Hide();

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("error");
        }
    }
```

I expect other forms to appear but nothing happens when I click login.

Comment: Are you getting any error message(s) when you debug?

Comment: i dont get any error at all

Comment: So when you debug, is the query pulling back data? Is is not the right data? You need to give more information about what is actually going wrong.  You said you tried other solutions based on searching the internet, post those solutions.

Comment: There are no errors at all. No data errors or anything wrong. when i make the textboxes empty or the uname and pword wrong, the right errors i set come out. but when i use the right ones, nothing happens. it stays still as if i was pressing no button at all

Comment: It sounds like you have validation on the front-end that is catching those errors, but you're saying the button click is not even registering? Please show the front-end HTML that has an event for the button click.

Comment: this isnt html. just c# system being made at visual studio. I followed both this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QrsZ4DPCgpg and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nvqeXdnJeFk but the same thing happened. no errors but the login button doesnt respond when right uname and pword are being typed

Comment: If there isn't any HTML, why do you have a button click event then? The button has to be clicked SOMEWHERE, and it should have this event tied to it.

Comment: that was for the login button. double clicking the button and login button and coding there is what you should do in visual studio. the one who made the vid also said that

Comment: Did you try to use break point to check the items in `dt`?